# c# iOS scrollView will not scroll

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I have a create account view which the user would use to create account in the system.  I've got the view laid out properly yet I am unable to scroll down.  I've looked all over the web for suggestions and the most prevalent was that the content was smaller or the same size as the scrollView.  I've added code to ensure that doesn't happen, but still cannot scroll.

My code:

```
public partial class createAccount : UIViewController
{
    public User MyUser;
    UIScrollView scrollView = new UIScrollView();
    public DataInterfaceWeb.DataInterface myService = new DataInterfaceWeb.DataInterface();
    List<string> Questions = new List<string>();
    public createAccount (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {

        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var height = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;
        View.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(255, 215, 0);
        nfloat bannerHeight = banner.Frame.Height;
        nfloat lblTitleHeight = lblTitle.Frame.Height;

        UILabel lblUsername = new UILabel();
        UITextField txtUsername = new UITextField();
        txtUsername.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
        lblUsername.Text = "Enter Username: ";
        txtUsername.Placeholder = "Enter Username";

        UILabel lblPassword = new UILabel();
        lblPassword.Text = "Enter Password: ";

        UITextField txtPassword = new UITextField();
        txtPassword.Placeholder = "Enter Password";
        txtPassword.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblConfirmPassword = new UILabel();
        lblConfirmPassword.Text = "Confirm Password: ";
        UITextField txtConfirmPassword = new UITextField();
        txtConfirmPassword.Placeholder = "Confirm Password";
        txtConfirmPassword.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblEmailAddress = new UILabel();
        lblEmailAddress.Text = "Enter Email Address: ";
        UITextField txtEmailAddress = new UITextField();
        txtEmailAddress.Placeholder = "Enter Email Address";
        txtEmailAddress.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblConfirmEmailAddress = new UILabel();
        lblConfirmEmailAddress.Text = "Confirm Email Address: ";
        UITextField txtConfirmEmailAddress = new UITextField();
        txtConfirmEmailAddress.Placeholder = "Confirm Email Address";
        txtConfirmEmailAddress.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblSelectQuestion = new UILabel();
        lblSelectQuestion.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        lblSelectQuestion.Text = "Select Challenge Question";

        UITextField challengeQuestion = new UITextField();
        challengeQuestion.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;
        challengeQuestion.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        challengeQuestion.Text = "Select Challenge Question";

        UILabel lblAnswer = new UILabel();
        lblAnswer.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        lblAnswer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray ;
        lblAnswer.Text = "Challenge Question Answer";

        UITextField txtChallengeAnswer = new UITextField();
        txtChallengeAnswer.Placeholder = "Enter Challenge Question Answer";
        txtChallengeAnswer.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;

        UILabel lblFirstName = new UILabel();
        lblFirstName.Text = "First Name: ";

        UITextField txtFirstName = new UITextField();
        txtFirstName.Placeholder = "Enter First Name";
        txtFirstName.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblMI = new UILabel();
        lblMI.Text = "Middle Initial: ";

        UITextField txtMI = new UITextField();
        txtMI.Placeholder = "MI";
        txtMI.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblLastName = new UILabel();
        lblLastName.Text = "Last Name: ";

        UITextField txtLastName = new UITextField();
        txtLastName.Placeholder = "Enter Last Name";
        txtLastName.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblSuffix = new UILabel();
        lblSuffix.Text = "Suffix: ";

        UITextField txtSuffix = new UITextField();
        txtSuffix.Text = "None";
        txtSuffix.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;

        UILabel lblAddress = new UILabel();
        lblAddress.Text = "Address: ";

        UITextField txtAddress = new UITextField();
        txtAddress.Placeholder = "Enter Address";
        txtAddress.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblCity = new UILabel();
        lblCity.Text = "City: ";

        UITextField txtCity = new UITextField();
        txtCity.Placeholder = "Enter City";
        txtCity.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblState = new UILabel();
        lblState.Text = "State: ";

        UITextField txtState = new UITextField();
        txtState.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;
        txtState.Text = "Select State";

        UILabel lblZip = new UILabel();
        lblZip.Text = "Zip: ";

        UITextField txtZip = new UITextField();
        txtZip.Placeholder = "Enter Zip";
        txtZip.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblPhone = new UILabel();
        lblPhone.Text = "Contact Phone:";

        UITextField txtPhone = new UITextField();
        txtPhone.Placeholder = "Enter Phone Number";
        txtPhone.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblSelectPhoneType = new UILabel();
        lblSelectPhoneType.Text = "Select Phone Type";

        UITextField txtSelectPhoneType = new UITextField();
        txtSelectPhoneType.Text = "Select Phone Type";
        txtSelectPhoneType.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;

        UILabel lblMessage = new UILabel();
        lblMessage.Text = "Select Company (if applicable) and department you are registering for.";
        lblMessage.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;

        lblMessage.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        // lblMessage.NumberOfLines = 0;

        UILabel lblSelectConference = new UILabel();
        lblSelectConference.Text = "Select Company (if applicable)";
        lblSelectConference.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;


        // scrollView.ContentSize = CGSize(;
        scrollView.Add(lblUsername);
        scrollView.Add(txtUsername);

        scrollView.Add(lblPassword);
        scrollView.Add(txtPassword);
        scrollView.Add(lblConfirmPassword);
        scrollView.Add(txtConfirmPassword);
        scrollView.Add(lblEmailAddress);
        scrollView.Add(txtEmailAddress);
        scrollView.Add(lblConfirmEmailAddress);
        scrollView.Add(txtConfirmEmailAddress);
        scrollView.Add(lblSelectQuestion);
        scrollView.Add(challengeQuestion);
        scrollView.Add(lblAnswer);
        scrollView.Add(txtChallengeAnswer);

        scrollView.Add(lblFirstName);
        scrollView.Add(txtFirstName);
        scrollView.Add(lblMI);
        scrollView.Add(txtMI);
        scrollView.Add(lblLastName);
        scrollView.Add(txtLastName);
        scrollView.Add(lblSuffix);
        scrollView.Add(txtSuffix);
        scrollView.Add(lblAddress);
        scrollView.Add(txtAddress);
        scrollView.Add(lblCity);
        scrollView.Add(txtCity);
        scrollView.Add(lblState);
        scrollView.Add(txtState);
        scrollView.Add(lblZip);
        scrollView.Add(txtZip);
        scrollView.Add(lblPhone);
        scrollView.Add(txtPhone);
        scrollView.Add(lblSelectPhoneType);
        scrollView.Add(txtSelectPhoneType);
        scrollView.Add(lblMessage);
        scrollView.Add(lblSelectConference);
        

        viewCreateAccount.Add(scrollView);

        scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.White;
        viewCreateAccount.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        viewCreateAccount.AddConstraints
        (
            banner.AtTopOf(View, height),
            banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
            banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),

            lblTitle.Below(banner, 0),
            lblTitle.WithSameWidth(banner),

            scrollView.Below(lblTitle,0),
            scrollView.AtBottomOf(View,10),
            scrollView.AtLeftOf(View,10),
            scrollView.AtRightOf(View,10)
        );

        scrollView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        scrollView.AddConstraints(
            lblUsername.AtTopOf(scrollView, 0),
            lblUsername.AtLeftOf(scrollView, 0),

            // txtUsername.Below(lblUsername, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtUsername.ToRightOf(lblUsername, 2),
            txtUsername.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblPassword.Below(lblUsername, 5),
            txtPassword.Below(lblUsername, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtPassword.ToRightOf(lblPassword, 2),
            txtPassword.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblConfirmPassword.Below(lblPassword, 5),
            txtConfirmPassword.Below(lblPassword, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtConfirmPassword.ToRightOf(lblConfirmPassword, 2),
            txtConfirmPassword.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblEmailAddress.Below(lblConfirmPassword, 5),
            txtEmailAddress.Below(lblConfirmPassword, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtEmailAddress.ToRightOf(lblEmailAddress, 2),
            txtEmailAddress.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblConfirmEmailAddress.Below(lblEmailAddress, 5),
            txtConfirmEmailAddress.Below(lblEmailAddress, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtConfirmEmailAddress.ToRightOf(lblConfirmEmailAddress, 2),
            txtConfirmEmailAddress.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblSelectQuestion.Below(lblConfirmEmailAddress).Plus(10),
            lblSelectQuestion.WithSameWidth(scrollView),

            challengeQuestion.WithSameWidth(scrollView),
            challengeQuestion.Below(lblSelectQuestion, 5).Plus(5),

            lblAnswer.Below(challengeQuestion, 5).Plus(5),
            lblAnswer.WithSameWidth(scrollView),

            txtChallengeAnswer.Below(lblAnswer).Plus(5),
            txtChallengeAnswer.WithSameWidth(scrollView),

            lblFirstName.Below(txtChallengeAnswer, 5),
            txtFirstName.Below(txtChallengeAnswer, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtFirstName.ToRightOf(lblFirstName, 2),
            txtFirstName.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblMI.Below(lblFirstName, 5),
            txtMI.Below(lblFirstName, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtMI.ToRightOf(lblMI, 2),
            txtMI.Width().EqualTo(50.0f),

            lblLastName.Below(lblMI, 5),
            txtLastName.Below(lblMI, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtLastName.ToRightOf(lblLastName, 2),
            txtLastName.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblSuffix.Below(lblLastName, 5),
            txtSuffix.Below(lblLastName, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtSuffix.ToRightOf(lblSuffix, 2),
            txtSuffix.Width().EqualTo(50.0f),

            lblAddress.Below(lblSuffix, 5),
            txtAddress.Below(lblSuffix, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtAddress.ToRightOf(lblAddress, 2),
            txtAddress.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblCity.Below(lblAddress, 5),
            txtCity.Below(lblAddress, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtCity.ToRightOf(lblCity, 2),
            txtCity.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblState.Below(lblCity, 5),
            txtState.Below(lblCity, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtState.ToRightOf(lblState, 2),
            txtState.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblZip.Below(lblState, 5),
            txtZip.Below(lblState, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtZip.ToRightOf(lblZip, 2),
            txtZip.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblPhone.Below(lblZip, 5),
            txtPhone.Below(lblZip, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtPhone.ToRightOf(lblPhone, 2),
            txtPhone.Width().EqualTo(200.0f),

            lblSelectPhoneType.Below(lblPhone, 5).Plus(5),
            lblSelectPhoneType.WithSameWidth(scrollView),

            txtSelectPhoneType.WithSameWidth(scrollView),
            txtSelectPhoneType.Below(lblSelectPhoneType, 5).Plus(5),

            //lblMessage.WithSameWidth(scrollView),
            lblMessage.Below(txtSelectPhoneType, 10).Plus(5),
            lblMessage.Width().EqualTo(350.0f),

            lblSelectConference.Below(lblMessage, 5).Plus(5),
            lblSelectConference.WithSameWidth(scrollView)

      );
        DataSet MyQuestionsDataset = myService.GetQuestions(myusername, mypassword, "REGISTRATION", "EN");
        Questions.Add("Select Challenge Question");
        foreach (DataRow MyDataRow in MyQuestionsDataset.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Questions.Add(MyDataRow["QUESTION"].ToString());

        };


        ConfigureChallengePicker(challengeQuestion, Questions);

        // Ensure content area is larger than scroll view
        var frame = scrollView.Frame;
        frame.Height += 250;
        scrollView.ContentSize = frame.Size;
        scrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;
    }

    void ConfigureChallengePicker(UITextField pickerTextField, List<string> theData)
    {
        PickerViewModel MyModel = new PickerViewModel();
        MyModel._pickerSource = theData;
        var picker = new UIPickerView
        {
            Model = MyModel,
            ShowSelectionIndicator = true
        };
        var screenWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        var pickerToolBar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)screenWidth, 44)) { BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default, Translucent = true };
        var flexibleSpaceButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);
        var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, (sender, e) => pickerTextField.ResignFirstResponder());
        doneButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            pickerTextField.Text = MyModel.SelectedItem;
        };
        pickerToolBar.SetItems(new[] { flexibleSpaceButton, doneButton }, false);

        pickerTextField.InputView = picker;
        pickerTextField.InputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi , what's the `viewCreateAccount` ? This may affect the scrolling of scrollview . You can check  whether `viewCreateAccount` can invoke touch event first .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, apparently I didn't set a large enough frame for the scroll view content size. In any event, I changed my code to:

```
public partial class createAccount : UIViewController
{
    public User MyUser;
    UIScrollView scrollView;

    public DataInterfaceWeb.DataInterface myService = new DataInterfaceWeb.DataInterface();
    List<string> Questions = new List<string>();

    float h = 50.0f;
    float w = 50.0f;
    float padding = 10.0f;
    int n = 25;


    public createAccount (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {

        scrollView = new UIScrollView
        {
            Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, viewCreateAccount.Frame.Width, h + 2 * padding),
            ContentSize = new SizeF((w + padding), (h + padding) * n),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray,
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
        };

        base.ViewDidLoad();
        var height = this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;
        View.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(255, 215, 0);
        nfloat bannerHeight = banner.Frame.Height;
        nfloat lblTitleHeight = lblTitle.Frame.Height;

        UILabel lblUsername = new UILabel();
        UITextField txtUsername = new UITextField();
        txtUsername.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
        lblUsername.Text = "Enter Username: ";
        txtUsername.Placeholder = "Enter Username";

        UILabel lblPassword = new UILabel();
        lblPassword.Text = "Enter Password: ";

        UITextField txtPassword = new UITextField();
        txtPassword.Placeholder = "Enter Password";
        txtPassword.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblConfirmPassword = new UILabel();
        lblConfirmPassword.Text = "Confirm Password: ";
        UITextField txtConfirmPassword = new UITextField();
        txtConfirmPassword.Placeholder = "Confirm Password";
        txtConfirmPassword.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblEmailAddress = new UILabel();
        lblEmailAddress.Text = "Enter Email Address: ";
        UITextField txtEmailAddress = new UITextField();
        txtEmailAddress.Placeholder = "Enter Email Address";
        txtEmailAddress.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblConfirmEmailAddress = new UILabel();
        lblConfirmEmailAddress.Text = "Confirm Email Address: ";
        UITextField txtConfirmEmailAddress = new UITextField();
        txtConfirmEmailAddress.Placeholder = "Confirm Email Address";
        txtConfirmEmailAddress.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblSelectQuestion = new UILabel();
        lblSelectQuestion.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        lblSelectQuestion.Text = "Select Challenge Question";

        UITextField challengeQuestion = new UITextField();
        challengeQuestion.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;
        challengeQuestion.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        challengeQuestion.Text = "Select Challenge Question";

        UILabel lblAnswer = new UILabel();
        lblAnswer.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        lblAnswer.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray ;
        lblAnswer.Text = "Challenge Question Answer";

        UITextField txtChallengeAnswer = new UITextField();
        txtChallengeAnswer.Placeholder = "Enter Challenge Question Answer";
        txtChallengeAnswer.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;

        UILabel lblFirstName = new UILabel();
        lblFirstName.Text = "First Name: ";

        UITextField txtFirstName = new UITextField();
        txtFirstName.Placeholder = "Enter First Name";
        txtFirstName.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblMI = new UILabel();
        lblMI.Text = "Middle Initial: ";

        UITextField txtMI = new UITextField();
        txtMI.Placeholder = "MI";
        txtMI.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblLastName = new UILabel();
        lblLastName.Text = "Last Name: ";

        UITextField txtLastName = new UITextField();
        txtLastName.Placeholder = "Enter Last Name";
        txtLastName.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblSuffix = new UILabel();
        lblSuffix.Text = "Suffix: ";

        UITextField txtSuffix = new UITextField();
        txtSuffix.Text = "None";
        txtSuffix.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;

        UILabel lblAddress = new UILabel();
        lblAddress.Text = "Address: ";

        UITextField txtAddress = new UITextField();
        txtAddress.Placeholder = "Enter Address";
        txtAddress.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblCity = new UILabel();
        lblCity.Text = "City: ";

        UITextField txtCity = new UITextField();
        txtCity.Placeholder = "Enter City";
        txtCity.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblState = new UILabel();
        lblState.Text = "State: ";

        UITextField txtState = new UITextField();
        txtState.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;
        txtState.Text = "Select State";

        UILabel lblZip = new UILabel();
        lblZip.Text = "Zip: ";

        UITextField txtZip = new UITextField();
        txtZip.Placeholder = "Enter Zip";
        txtZip.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblPhone = new UILabel();
        lblPhone.Text = "Contact Phone:";

        UITextField txtPhone = new UITextField();
        txtPhone.Placeholder = "Enter Phone Number";
        txtPhone.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;

        UILabel lblSelectPhoneType = new UILabel();
        lblSelectPhoneType.Text = "Select Phone Type";

        UITextField txtSelectPhoneType = new UITextField();
        txtSelectPhoneType.Text = "Select Phone Type";
        txtSelectPhoneType.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;

        UILabel lblMessage = new UILabel();
        lblMessage.Text = "Select Company (if applicable) and Department you are registering for.";
        lblMessage.TextColor = UIKit.UIColor.Blue;

        lblMessage.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;

        UILabel lblSelectCompany = new UILabel();
        lblSelectCompany .Text = "Select Company (if applicable)";
        lblSelectCompany .TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;


        // scrollView.ContentSize = CGSize(;
        scrollView.Add(lblUsername);
        scrollView.Add(txtUsername);

        scrollView.Add(lblPassword);
        scrollView.Add(txtPassword);
        scrollView.Add(lblConfirmPassword);
        scrollView.Add(txtConfirmPassword);
        scrollView.Add(lblEmailAddress);
        scrollView.Add(txtEmailAddress);
        scrollView.Add(lblConfirmEmailAddress);
        scrollView.Add(txtConfirmEmailAddress);
        scrollView.Add(lblSelectQuestion);
        scrollView.Add(challengeQuestion);
        scrollView.Add(lblAnswer);
        scrollView.Add(txtChallengeAnswer);

        scrollView.Add(lblFirstName);
        scrollView.Add(txtFirstName);
        scrollView.Add(lblMI);
        scrollView.Add(txtMI);
        scrollView.Add(lblLastName);
        scrollView.Add(txtLastName);
        scrollView.Add(lblSuffix);
        scrollView.Add(txtSuffix);
        scrollView.Add(lblAddress);
        scrollView.Add(txtAddress);
        scrollView.Add(lblCity);
        scrollView.Add(txtCity);
        scrollView.Add(lblState);
        scrollView.Add(txtState);
        scrollView.Add(lblZip);
        scrollView.Add(txtZip);
        scrollView.Add(lblPhone);
        scrollView.Add(txtPhone);
        scrollView.Add(lblSelectPhoneType);
        scrollView.Add(txtSelectPhoneType);
        scrollView.Add(lblMessage);
        scrollView.Add(lblSelectCompany);
        

        viewCreateAccount.Add(scrollView);

        scrollView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.White;
        viewCreateAccount.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        viewCreateAccount.AddConstraints
        (
            banner.AtTopOf(View, height),
            banner.AtRightOf(View, 0),
            banner.AtLeftOf(View, 0),

            lblTitle.Below(banner, 0),
            lblTitle.WithSameWidth(banner),

            scrollView.Below(lblTitle,0),
            scrollView.AtBottomOf(View,10),
            scrollView.AtLeftOf(View,10),
            scrollView.AtRightOf(View,10)
        );

        scrollView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        scrollView.AddConstraints(
            lblUsername.AtTopOf(scrollView, 0),
            lblUsername.AtLeftOf(scrollView, 0),

            // txtUsername.Below(lblUsername, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtUsername.ToRightOf(lblUsername, 2),
            txtUsername.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblPassword.Below(lblUsername, 5),
            txtPassword.Below(lblUsername, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtPassword.ToRightOf(lblPassword, 2),
            txtPassword.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblConfirmPassword.Below(lblPassword, 5),
            txtConfirmPassword.Below(lblPassword, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtConfirmPassword.ToRightOf(lblConfirmPassword, 2),
            txtConfirmPassword.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblEmailAddress.Below(lblConfirmPassword, 5),
            txtEmailAddress.Below(lblConfirmPassword, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtEmailAddress.ToRightOf(lblEmailAddress, 2),
            txtEmailAddress.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblConfirmEmailAddress.Below(lblEmailAddress, 5),
            txtConfirmEmailAddress.Below(lblEmailAddress, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtConfirmEmailAddress.ToRightOf(lblConfirmEmailAddress, 2),
            txtConfirmEmailAddress.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblSelectQuestion.Below(lblConfirmEmailAddress).Plus(10),
            lblSelectQuestion.WithSameWidth(scrollView),

            challengeQuestion.WithSameWidth(scrollView),
            challengeQuestion.Below(lblSelectQuestion, 5).Plus(5),

            lblAnswer.Below(challengeQuestion, 5).Plus(5),
            lblAnswer.WithSameWidth(scrollView),

            txtChallengeAnswer.Below(lblAnswer).Plus(5),
            txtChallengeAnswer.WithSameWidth(scrollView),

            lblFirstName.Below(txtChallengeAnswer, 5),
            txtFirstName.Below(txtChallengeAnswer, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtFirstName.ToRightOf(lblFirstName, 2),
            txtFirstName.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblMI.Below(lblFirstName, 5),
            txtMI.Below(lblFirstName, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtMI.ToRightOf(lblMI, 2),
            txtMI.Width().EqualTo(50.0f),

            lblLastName.Below(lblMI, 5),
            txtLastName.Below(lblMI, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtLastName.ToRightOf(lblLastName, 2),
            txtLastName.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblSuffix.Below(lblLastName, 5),
            txtSuffix.Below(lblLastName, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtSuffix.ToRightOf(lblSuffix, 2),
            txtSuffix.Width().EqualTo(50.0f),

            lblAddress.Below(lblSuffix, 5),
            txtAddress.Below(lblSuffix, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtAddress.ToRightOf(lblAddress, 2),
            txtAddress.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblCity.Below(lblAddress, 5),
            txtCity.Below(lblAddress, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtCity.ToRightOf(lblCity, 2),
            txtCity.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblState.Below(lblCity, 5),
            txtState.Below(lblCity, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtState.ToRightOf(lblState, 2),
            txtState.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblZip.Below(lblState, 5),
            txtZip.Below(lblState, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtZip.ToRightOf(lblZip, 2),
            txtZip.Width().EqualTo(250.0f),

            lblPhone.Below(lblZip, 5),
            txtPhone.Below(lblZip, 0).Plus(5), // add below margin
            txtPhone.ToRightOf(lblPhone, 2),
            txtPhone.Width().EqualTo(200.0f),

            lblSelectPhoneType.Below(lblPhone, 5).Plus(5),
            lblSelectPhoneType.WithSameWidth(scrollView),

            txtSelectPhoneType.WithSameWidth(scrollView),
            txtSelectPhoneType.Below(lblSelectPhoneType, 5).Plus(5),

            //lblMessage.WithSameWidth(scrollView),
            lblMessage.Below(txtSelectPhoneType, 10).Plus(5),
            lblMessage.Width().EqualTo(350.0f),

            lblSelectCompany.Below(lblMessage, 5).Plus(5),
            lblSelectCompany.WithSameWidth(scrollView)

      );
        DataSet MyQuestionsDataset = myOMLService.GetQuestions(myusername, mypassword, "REGISTRATION", "EN");
        Questions.Add("Select Challenge Question");
        foreach (DataRow MyDataRow in MyQuestionsDataset.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Questions.Add(MyDataRow["QUESTION"].ToString());

        };


        ConfigureChallengePicker(challengeQuestion, Questions);

    }

    void ConfigureChallengePicker(UITextField pickerTextField, List<string> theData)
    {
        PickerViewModel MyModel = new PickerViewModel();
        MyModel._pickerSource = theData;
        var picker = new UIPickerView
        {
            Model = MyModel,
            ShowSelectionIndicator = true
        };
        var screenWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
        var pickerToolBar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)screenWidth, 44)) { BarStyle = UIBarStyle.Default, Translucent = true };
        var flexibleSpaceButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);
        var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, (sender, e) => pickerTextField.ResignFirstResponder());
        doneButton.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            pickerTextField.Text = MyModel.SelectedItem;
        };
        pickerToolBar.SetItems(new[] { flexibleSpaceButton, doneButton }, false);

        pickerTextField.InputView = picker;
        pickerTextField.InputAccessoryView = pickerToolBar;
    }
}
```

Scrolls nicely now although the frame size is a bit much, I'll have to figure a way to calculate that by the amount of content, you'd think that would be built in, but no.

Comment: Hi , remember to mark the answer when you have time , it will help others who have similar issue. :-)